# Find equation of circles using parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry

Parabola $y=\frac{1}{16}x^2-\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{25}{4}$

A line passing through the origin and point $(6,8)$ and $x$-axis are tangents to the circles that I'm supposed to find.

How can I find the equation of the circles using this information and the given parabola?

Comment: What is a "line passing through the origin and point (6,8) and x-axis" ??? And where does the parabola come into play ?

Comment: How is the parabola relevant here? Does it pass through the circle center?

Comment: Not very polite to ignore the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is given by
$$ (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$$
The two lines that should be tangent to the circle are given by
\begin{align}
y &= \frac{4}{3}x\\
y &= 0\\
\end{align}
For the circle to be tangent to these lines the center of the circle should be in the middle of these lines, to be precise on the line
$$y = \frac{2}{3}x$$ 
And thus the radius is $\frac{2}{3}a$. The general equation (before taking the parabola into account) is
$$ (x-a)^2 + (y-\frac{2}{3}a)^2 = \left(\frac{2}{3}a\right)^2 $$
We now use the parabola to find the last constrait on $a$

Comment: I am always amazed to see how people are able to answer completely unintelligible questions.

Comment: You are right, I am assuming a question.

Comment: *"We now use the parabola to find the last constraint on $a$"* ... I suppose that's the prudent place to stop, since the problem statement doesn't explain *how* to use the parabola. (Is the circle *centered* on the parabola? *tangent* to it? Does it *pass through the focus?* the *vertex?* *something else?* Who knows?)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that your problem is hard to understand. May it be the following?

## Problem

Find the equation of the circle such that

1. the center of the circle lies on the parabola $y=\dfrac{1}{16}x^2-\dfrac{3}{4}x+\dfrac{25}{4}$;
2. the circle is tangent to the line passing through $(0,0),(6,8)$ and the $x-$axis.

[image]

Comment: If that's *not* the problem statement, it should be ... although it's a bit of a shame to have the exercise presented as an algebraic slog. There's some really nice geometry going on here (as your image suggests you already know). $(6,8)$ isn't just some random point: it's the parabola's *focus*. Moreover, the $x$-axis is its directrix. The two angle bisectors are naturally perpendicular, and they're tangent to the parabola at the circles' centers, which in turn define a *focal chord*, which itself is perpendicular to the line through the origin and $(6,8)$. Neat stuff!